# Quitar espacio entre el borde y una imagen

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo un problema! Me queda un espacio entre la imagen y el borde de página y lo quiero eliminar, pero no puedo.
Lo que hice es esto:

[image: Como me quedó]

Y mi código es este. (HTML)

```
<header class="encabezado">
    <div class="container logo-nav-container">
        <img src="Imagenes/DISCOR SIN FONDO.webp" alt="Discor: Cerrajería y Accesorios" width="150" height="50">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="Nuestra Empresa.html">Rubros</a></li>
                <li><a href="Nuestra Empresa.html">Nuestra Empresa</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="Novedades.html">Novedades</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

En los estilos tengo esto. (CSS)

```
body{
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', 'serif', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    font: 1,2rem;
    line-height: 1,3em;
    margin: 0;
    
}
.encabezado{
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.encabezado a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo-nav-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}
.navigation ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
   .navigation ul li{
    display: inline-block;}

    .navigation ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .navigation ul li a:hover{
        background: #7ed957;
        color: #737373;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Eso es lo que tengo, cuando en realidad lo que quiero es algo similar a esto.

[image: Como me gustaría]

Quise hacer que el `<div class="encabezado">`estuviera justificado con `justify-content: space-between`, pero no funcionó. Además, intenté con el `align="left"`(Sé que no se usa más en HTML5), pero tampoco funcionó. Entonces me quedé sin opciones y recurro a ustedes.

Gracias y Saludos!

Comment: No logro obtener tu error. Por favor, realiza un [mre] que pueda probar, que contenga tu error. Yo solo logre esto, pero como puedes ver, no esta tu error. -> https://jsfiddle.net/0szj21of/

Comment: Que raro... No entiendo porqué podría ser. Ahí agregué la parte de Body, no sé si influiría.

Comment: Lo único que falta es la imagen en alguna url web para poder verla.

Comment: El padding de los elementos <a> genera un height de 62px y tu estableces el height de la imagen de 50px, eso genera que la imagen se centre verticalmente y aparezca ese espaciado "invisible" revisa haber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontre tu error, tu error radica en el padding de tus enlaces en vez de agregarles 1rem arriba y abajo, agrega 1.2rem asi:

```
.navigation ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

ya lo probe y funciona, la imagen ya se centro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]